# How to fight unwanted rotations when using "Stretch to" modifier?

Tags: rigging

I'm experimenting with a rig. I have a normal IK leg and 1 bone to help with stretches with "Stretch to" modifier. The problem is an unwanted rotation around its local Y whenever I move my IK chain to somewhat extreme angles. To demonstrate I've done a little video with this problem.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=17SfFueTWSU

[Blend file](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/35137) if someone want...

Comment: Use *track to* or *copy rotation* constraint before the *stretch to* one. Depends on your setup, a .blend file wouldn't hurt.

Comment: there is a video that shows whats a problem, but here is a blend [link](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/35137). P.S. looks like copy rotation does the trick, thx.